# What does this C function mean?

Tags: c, function

What does this function mean?

```
#define PROGRAM_SENTINEL ((char *)0x1)

void suppzSetSentinal(const char **prog, const char *key)
    {
        const char **tmp = prog;
        while (tmp && *tmp) {
            if (*tmp == PROGRAM_SENTINEL) {
                *tmp = key;
                break;
            }
            tmp++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code was written by someone that doesnt understand for-loops.

Answer (score 2):

The function scans its first argument, a `NULL` terminated array of pointers to `char`, for the special value `PROGRAM_SENTINEL` and replaces that with the pointer passed as the second argument named `key`.